# Route is not defined after updating laravel 5.1.8 to 5.1.24

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1, laravel-routing

I updated my laravel installation with the composer update and i get this error.

```
Route [categoryid] not defined
```

The strange thing is that, before the update, it worked just fine.
My routes.php file looks like this:

```
Route::group(['prefix'=>'category'], function () {

    Route::get('mobilephones', [
        'as'=>'mobilephones',
        'uses'=>'PhoneController@getShow'
    ]);

    Route::get('{categoryid}', [
        'as'=>'categoryid',
        'uses'=>'CategoryController@one'
    ]);

    Route::get('{categoryid}', [
        'as'=>'computerscategoryid',
        'uses'=>'CategoryController@one'
    ]);      
});
```

and i am calling the route with this html code

```
<li><a href="{{route('categoryid',['argument'])}}">Argument</a></li>
```

Everything used to work so is anyone aware of a change in the Group route files after 5.1.8?

Comment: Always run `php artisan route:list` to see your routes. If I were to guess, I'd say that because you have two routes that do the exact same thing but have different route names for some reason, one of them is overriding the other. I would suggest removing the `computerscategoryid` route.

Comment: @ThomasKim Thank you. That was it. I had 2 routes for SEO purposes but after removing the coumputerscategoryid it worked. If you want post it as an answer to approve it.

Comment: @George Done and thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a general rule, always run `php artisan route:list` to see the compiled list of your routes.

You have two routes that do the exact same thing:

```
Route::get('{categoryid}', [
    'as'=>'categoryid',
    'uses'=>'CategoryController@one'
]);

Route::get('{categoryid}', [
    'as'=>'computerscategoryid',
    'uses'=>'CategoryController@one'
]);
```

They accept the same argument. They get sent to the same controller action. The only difference is that they have different route names. One of them (the second one) is most likely overriding the other. I would suggest removing the second one - `computerscategoryid` - because I can't see a purpose in having both of them.